# Cordova - PhoneGap - InAppBrowser Script Interaction

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I just want to know if this is possible since I don't have any experience with Cordova \ PhoneGap before I start working on app.

I want to create mobile application from where I can browse any website and inject my custom JavaScript, and interact with that JavaScript from my mobile application, for example some events on mouse move or whatever.

I guess this will be enough:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
  var ref = window.open('http://www.example.com/', '_blank', 'location=yes, toolbar=yes, EnableViewPortScale=yes');
  ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
    ref.executeScript(
      { file: "http://www.some-other-domain.com/my-script.js" },
        function() {
           ref.executeScript({ code:'myMethod()' }, 
            function(value){
               alert(value);
             });
           }
        );
      }
   );
}
```

And in my-script.js for example:

```
var myMethod = function(){
   return "Lorem Ipsum";
};
```

My guess is that this will work, but just for first initial load when I call this `window.open` method, but I want to add this to every website, so how about that?

Comment: it will work on every loadstop event, so it should work everytime you load a website

Comment: @jcesarmobile can I also drag button from my toolbar on web page, in order to trigger mouse over for example like that?

Comment: no, you can't move the toolbar or the buttons

Comment: @jcesarmobile just to make sure that we are talking about the same thing, when I say toolbar I mean this http://prntscr.com/8gzkam for example to drag this plus button, basically this is just HTML, so I don't see why not?

Comment: I though you were talking about the inAppBrowser toolbar. Then, if you inject the code you need to drag the button, you should be able to do it